# Take percentage and convert it to 0% to 100% range?

Tags: percentages

Ok, so to calculate the percentage of a number i know that you do this for example if you want to find `5%` of `67` `(5/100)*67`

But let's say i have a number which let's call it `a` and it is equal to `500`, how would i take (for example) `88%` of `a` then take the answer and convert it to it's equivalent in a `0%` to `100%` range... Hopefully this question makes sense i am new to percentages and am not that good at them yet

Comment: you can write it as $88a/100$, that is first multiply a with 88 and then divide by 100.

Comment: But isn't the "equivalent in a 0% to 100% range" of 88% simply 88%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a touch confused.  The equivalent in $0\%$ to $100\%$ range, is already the value you started with: $88\%$.

And $88\%$ of $500$ is $\frac{88}{100}\times500=440$.

Another way of combining these numbers would be to say $88\%$ of some number $x$, is $500$.  Therefore you know $\frac{88}{100}\times x=500$.

So $x=500\times 100/88=568.\overline{18}$.

Finally, and I think this is what you are looking for, you might ask yourself, "what percentage of 500, is 88?"  In this case, you have the number $\frac{88}{500}$ and you simply need to convert it to a percentage, which means converting the denominator (the bottom of the fraction) to $100$ without changing the value of the fraction.  To do this you divide both the top and bottom of the fraction by 500 and then multiply them by 100.  This gives you $100$ on the bottom and $(88/5)$ on the top, which equals $17.6\%.$

What the percent symbol actually means is simply $\times\frac{1}{100}$.

The key to answering a question like this, is to start out by being crystal clear exactly what the question is in the first place.

Comment: Thanks you soo much! Exactly what i was looking for :)